# Efficient algorithm for computing Vandermonde determinant

Tags: matrices, algorithms, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

The determinant of Vandermonde matrix
$$V=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-1} \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-1} \\
1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & \cdots & x_3^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$
can be represented as a product of pairwise differences between $x_i$s:
$$\det(V)=\prod_{i<j}x_j-x_i.$$
Is there an algorithm that computes this determinant more quickly than by trivially multiplying those $O(n^2)$ differences?

Comment: See the on-line MDPI document entitled (somewhat strangely) "Recursive matrix calculation paradigm by the example of structured matrix" by Jerzy S. Respondek

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I will provide a sub-quadratic algorithm.

## Assumptions & Definitions

- Let $\mathbb{F}$ be some field
- Let $M(n)$ be the cost of a polynomial multiplication algorithm over $\mathbb{F}.$ And suppose that :
  $$
  2M(\tfrac{n}{2})  \le M(n)
  $$

We will define $\Phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ as the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix $V:$
$$
V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 & \dots & x_1^{n-1} \\
1 & x_2 & \dots & x_2^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots &\vdots \\
1& x_{n} & \dots & x_{n}^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

## Algorithm

- Let $n\in\mathbb{N},$ and let $m=\lfloor \tfrac{n}{2} \rfloor$
- Let $\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{F}^n.$
- We will assume that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are pairwise distinct as otherwise, $\Phi(\boldsymbol{x})=0.$

### 1. Recursion

We have the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
\Phi(\boldsymbol{x}) &=  \prod_{1\le i<j \le n} x_j-x_i \\
&= \Phi(x_1,\dots,x_m) \times \Phi(x_{m+1},\dots,x_n) \times \prod_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j=m+1}^{n}x_j-x_i  \\
&=\Phi(\boldsymbol{x}') \times \Phi(\boldsymbol{x''}) \times  \chi(\boldsymbol{x}',\boldsymbol{x''})
\end{align*}
$$
Where $\boldsymbol{x}'=(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ and $\boldsymbol{x}''=(x_{m+1},\dots,x_n)$

### 2. Calculating $\chi$

Now we arrived to two recursive calculations of $\Phi$ plus one evaluation of the term:
$$
\chi(\boldsymbol{x}',\boldsymbol{x}'')=\prod_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j=m+1}^{n}x_j-x_i 
$$
This term has to be efficiently calculated to get a sub-quadratic complexity. **Fortunately, This is in fact possible**

To demonstrate this, We will define the polynomial $H$ as follows:
$$
H(t)=\chi(\boldsymbol{x}',t)=\prod_{i=1}^{m}t-x_i
$$
Now it is very clear that $\chi(\boldsymbol{x}',\boldsymbol{x}'') = \prod_{j=m+1}^{n} H(x_j).$ And with that, we only have to evaluate the polynomial $H$ at the $n-m$ points. This can be done in $\mathcal{O}(M(n) \log n)$ using **[fast multi-point evaluation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/polynomial.html#multi-point-evaluation)**

### 3. Complexity

Now, let $T_n$ the cost of **Algorithm 1** at the worst-case scenario:
$$
T_n = T_{m} + T_{n-m} + \mathcal{O}(M(n) \log n)
$$

With that, we can easily deduce that:
$$
T_n = \mathcal{O}\left(M(n)\cdot  (\log n)^2\right) 
$$

If $\mathbb{F}$ allows a $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ polynomial multiplication algorithm (FFT-based), we get:
$$
T_n= \mathcal{O}(n (\log n)^3)
$$

---